# createBottomTabNavigator in React-navigation 3 , not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

```
   const MainFooterNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
{
        Feeds: {
            screen: FeedsScreen
        },
        Camera: {
            screen: CameraScreen
        },
        Profile: {
            screen: ProfileScreen
        }
    },
)



const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {

        AuthFlow: {
            screen: AuthNavigator 
        },
        MainFlow: {
            screen: MainFooterNavigator
        } 
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'AuthFlow'
    }   
)


module.exports = {
        AppContainer: createAppContainer(AppNavigator)
}
```

This AppContainer is used in App.js as

```
 <View>
      <AppContainer/>
 </View>
```

Not getting Bottom tab navigator when MainFlow is loaded . Please help me out ,
Is i am doing any thing wrong.
working with react-navigation 3 (latest)

Comment: Could you show us your MainFlow component.